# createoptional fields embed field on my discord bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hello fellow programmers.  I am trying to add the slash command (field) option to my Discord bot but each time the embed message is launched the bot crashes

I did like this but it doesn't work (without the fields it works very well)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqh2G.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH4Xp.png)

so the bot starts, I have the option (Field) in slash command:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBNrG.png)

But when I fill in everything and send the embed to the channel the bot crashes and gives me this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9YJJ.png)

I am attaching the js code hoping that someone can help me add 2 or 3 fields that is enough for the embed messages to be clearer to read

```
class command {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "embed"
        this.description = "Embed builder."
        this.options = [
            { type: 7, name: "channel", description: "The channel where the bot will send the embed.", required: false },
            { type: 3, name: "title", description: "The embed title.", required: false },
            { type: 3, name: "description", description: "The embed description.", required: false },
            { type: 3, name: "image", description: "The embed image.", required: false },
            { type: 3, name: "color", description: "The embed color.", required: false },
            { type: 3, name: "author", description: "The embed author.", required: false },
            { type: 3, name: "url", description: "The embed url.", required: false },
            { type: 3, name: "thumbnail", description: "The embed thumbnail.", required: false },
            { type: 3, name: "footer", description: "The embed footer.", required: false },
            { type: 3, name: "footer-image", description: "The embed footer image. Only works if there is already a footer.", required: false },
            { type: 3, name: "field", description: "The embed field.", required: false },
        ]
    }

    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const channel = interaction.options.getChannel("channel")
        const title = interaction.options.getString("title")
        const description = interaction.options.getString("description")
        const image = interaction.options.getString("image")
        const color = interaction.options.getString("color")
        const author = interaction.options.getString("author")
        const url = interaction.options.getString("url")
        const thumbnail = interaction.options.getString("thumbnail")
        const footer = interaction.options.getString("footer")
        const footerImage = interaction.options.getString("footer-image")
        const field = interaction.option.getString("field")

        if(channel && (channel.type !== "GUILD_TEXT")) return interaction.reply({ content: "The channel must be a text channel.", ephemeral: true })

        

        try {
            const embeds = [{
                title: title,
                description: description ?? "** **",
                image: { url: image },
                color: color,
                author: { name: author, url: url },
                thumbnail: { url: thumbnail },
                footer: { text: footer, iconURL: footerImage },
                field: { text: field },
            }]
            interaction.reply({ content: "Done!", ephemeral: true })
            if(channel) {
                channel.send({
                    embeds: embeds
                })
            } else {
                interaction.channel.send({
                    embeds: embeds
                })
            }
        } catch(e) {
            interaction.reply("An error has occurred while sending the embed.")
        }
    }
}

module.exports = command
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. You are trying to call the `getString` function on the `interaction.option` object, while you should call the function from the `interaction.options` object (you forgot the `s` at the end of `option`).

Comment: hello thank you for your good eye :) suddenly the bot does not crash anymore! but the field is not in the embed message...

Comment: Discord looks for a `fields` objects to be an array of objects with `name` and a `value`